# Sitecore: RTE Paste as Plain Text customization

Tags: sitecore, rte, sitecore8

I was experimenting with RTE buttons and found that the copy pasting from word to RTE allows all styles to be intact. So i read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406415/sitecore-forcing-pasting-as-unformatted-text) and got rid of the extra formatting. Now i want to deal with blank spaces and line breaks. So, with some analysis i have decided to allow:

One blank space for single line break. Statements to be shown as single paragraph.For example

```
    "This is new. </br> This is weird." should become "<p>This is new. &nbsp;This is weird.</p>"
```

If multiple line breaks are found, then all break separated statements should act as single paragraph with only single break between them. For example

```
    "This is new. </br></br></br> This is weird." should become "<p>This is new.</p> </br> <p>This is weird.</p>"
```

This would be very efficient for authors which previously would need to adjust the whole scrap after pasting from word.

I have tried using the "Paste as Plain Text" button but it does not take care of line breaks. So i was wondering how i could customize the button function to adjust it to my needs? where and how should i do this ??

Answer (score 1):

In web.config file, you can change and update HTMLEditor setting. 
However, you might have different aspect and dynamic user's input in the HTML editor. So, I would suggest you create a customize RichText Editor in Core DB and an assembly if you need. Then, create another config file in App_include folder to patch and add your customized HTML editor with different setting. 
Below is from web.config file and you can update this configuration if you want to keep using default RichText Editor.

```xml
<!--  HTML EDITOR DEFAULT CONFIGURATION TYPE 
    Specifies the type responsible for setting up the rich text editor. Can be overriden at profile level. Must inherit from 
    Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration,Sitecore.Client.
    Default value: Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration,Sitecore.Client
-->
    <setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultConfigurationType" value="Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration,Sitecore.Client" />
<!--  HTML EDITOR DEFAULT PROFILE
Path to the default html editor profile.
Default value: /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default
-->
    <setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default" />
<!--  HTML EDITOR LINE BREAK
Specifies the tag that the HTML editor inserts on Enter. Values can be
"br", "div" and "p".
-->
    <setting name="HtmlEditor.LineBreak" value="p" />
<!--  HTML EDITOR REMOVE SCRIPTS
If true, the rich text editor removes script tags from RTE field values before saving. Setting the value to true reduces the potential for cross-site scripting and other script-related issues.
Default value: true
-->
    <setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true" />
<!--  HTML EDITOR SUPPORT WEB CONTROLS
Indicates if the Html Editor supports web controls. If true, Web Controls are shown as yellow boxes.
Default value: true
-->
    <setting name="HtmlEditor.SupportWebControls" value="true" />
<!--  HTML EDITOR VALIDATOR SERVICE URL
Specifies the url that validates XHtml.
-->
    <setting name="HtmlEditor.ValidatorServiceUrl" value="http://validator.w3.org/check" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this change in your Javascript... you can have custom JS when you are in authoring mode to catch the paste event and do the HTML manipulation in javascript...
An other option that would work as well in the ContentTree would be to add a button in the RTE that call this javascript, here you can find some explanation on how to add the button to the RTE. 
https://markstiles.net/Blog/2011/02/05/adding-button-to-rich-text-editor.aspx